# jquery text change when input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can we do like the bottom, the simple way ?

[image] ?

it updates when we change the input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say you had the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox"/>

<span>http://twitter.com/<span id="changeable_text"></span></span>
```

Your JS would **listen for the [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event.**

```
$('input#textbox').keyup(function() {
   //perform ajax call...
   $('#changeable_text').text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: or use the .keyup, .keypressed functions if you want changes to happen as they are typed, the .change will only fire once the focus is lost.

Answer (score 6):

Just attach to the `keyup` event of that textbox and update a span accordingly.

**The textbox and span**

```
<input type="text" id="txt-url-suffix" />
<div>Your public profile: http://www.twitter.com/<span id="url-suffix" /></div>
```

**And some simple jQuery**

```
var $urlSuffix = $("#url-suffix");
$("#txt-url-suffix").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $urlSuffix.text(value);
});
```

Comment: thanks!, yeah i just cant figure the logic, btw after ive search the jquery docs i found keyup. thanks again marko